# ListBox ... get all child items that are visible in the UI? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox`.

I need to get a list of all items that are visible in the UI.

How does one go about doing that?

Comment: Does this help? [Determining the Visibility of Elements inside Scrollviewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/01/18/elements-visibility-inside-scrollviewer.aspx). In your case, substitute `ListBox` for `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
listbox.Items.Cast<UIElement>().Where(x => x.IsVisible)
```

Comment: Won't work if Items contains data items rather than UIElements, which is normally the case.

Comment: That is true but shouldn't you be wrapping any data in a ListBoxItem?

Comment: No, not necesarily..if it is databound to a collection of class objects, we cannot cast it to UIElement...

Comment: @Rob: if you've bound an ItemsControl to a data source, it will automatically wrap data items in a container (ListBoxItem in this case). However, it doesn't expose those containers through the Items collection - that collection will still contain the original data items as you'd expect. To get at the containers, you need to use the ItemContainerGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

For get all Controls use this code

```
foreach (var item in list.Items)
{
     var myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
     DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
     TextBox tb = (TextBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("tb", myContentPresenter);
}
```

FindVisualChild method:

```
 private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is childItem)
                {
                    return (childItem)child;
                }
                else
                {
                    childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null)
                        return childOfChild;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

XAML looks like this:

```
...
<ListBox Name="list">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox x:Name="tb"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
...
```